# How to upgrade redis on debian 8

Tags: debian, redis

I have redis `2.8.17` installed on Debian 8 through `apt install redis-server`. I'd like to upgrade to be able to use some newer features. How can I do so?

I've tried to get new version by making redis from source as explained [here](https://msyarif04.wordpress.com/2017/12/20/how-to-install-redis-server-on-debian-8/) but then redis server daemon will not work.

Also I tried to install from `chris-lea` respository, as indicated [here](https://chilts.org/installing-redis-from-chris-leas-ppa/) but then when I update I get

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

So I'm left clueless and appreciate your hints.

Comment: Those directions are for Ubuntu, not Debian.

Comment: So how to do that on Ubuntu? I could not find any instructions about that.